# preg_match post-id

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to get the post-id my posts.
this is the format it is in--> postid-785645
the numbers are randomly generated.

```
<?php
$mysite = "http://example.com";
$wholepage = @file_get_contents($mysite);

// I want to use preg_match to echo just the numbers. out of the whole page.
// Basically i'm trying to have is search the whole page for -> postid-(randomly generated number) and have it echo the number from things that are in this format.

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the following regular expression:

```
"/postid-[0-9]+/"
```

Example code:

```
$wholepage = 'foo postid-785645 bar postid-785646 baz';
$matches = array();
$string = preg_match_all("/postid-[0-9]+/", $wholepage, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => postid-785645
            [1] => postid-785646
        )

)
```

I'm using [**`preg_match_all`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead of [**`preg_match`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) because `preg_match` stops after it finds the first match.